# What does it mean when it says "you should not be parsing the "text" field. in getting the top 10 hash tags

Tags: python

I have an twitter assignment in python where i need to write a program top_ten.py that computes the ten most frequently occuring hash tags from a twitter stream that was put into a .txt file.  What does it mean when it says"  You should not be parsing the "text" field?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: What's the specific error message? What's the context?

Comment: Probably there is a hastag field and you should get this field and get the 10 more used. If you post the .txt file or at least 2 tweets it would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API returns tweets [in a form like](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)

```
{
  "entities": {
    "hashtags": [
      {
        "text": "freebandnames",
        "indices": [
          20,
          34
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "text": "Aggressive Ponytail #freebandnames"
}
```

(Many, many fields have been removed for clarity.) Your assignment probably means that you should examine hashtags by looking at the `hashtags` list in the `entities` object instead of trying to parse the `text` field to find the hashtags yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your mean by 'text field' since you have not provided an example of a .txt file and your python code.

However, if there is simply one hashtag on each line of the text file and all you have to do is print out the top 10 most frequent hashtags, then this will do it:

```
hashtags = {}

with open('hashtags.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        hashtag = line.strip()
        if hashtag in tweets:
            hashtags[hashtag] += 1
        else:
            hashtags[hashtag] = 1

top10 = sorted([[item[1], item[0]] for item in hashtags.items()], reversed=True)[:10]
for hashtag, frequency in top10:
    print(hashtag, frequency)
```